How do I get the brand taxonomy slug to build my own url in Elementor loop grid widget
I'm using Elementor Pro, Woocommerce Brands and Search and Filter Pro plugins.
I use the Elementor Loop Grid widget to display all brand logos. But instead of linking them to the brands page, I want them to link to the shop with the brand filter (built with Search and Filter Pro) activated.
I tried to build the url myself in a shortcode, but can't manage to get the slug of the brand. How can I build my custom url?
The brands page: https://oepsiepoepsie.valerieeskens.be/merken
The shop page with filter activated: https://oepsiepoepsie.valerieeskens.be/shop?_sft_product_brand=baby-on-the-move1

Here's what you can do....Create a custom post type using ACF, create a URL field and then add your brand name as title and then brand image as featured image.
This is so you can map it using loop grid.
Once that is done you can use the URL field to link to each brand filter page.
